# How to allow administrators to store encrypted data for users, but not developers or others, of an application?

Tags: security, encryption

I have a set of encrypted financial data for investors and need to store it in a database. The investors must be able to see the data when logged in to the app but the developers and everyone else mustn ot be able to see it.

Additionally the investors are not tech savvy and can not be given a key to use apart from a username and password.

What technologies/encryption approaches can I take with the app so that the financial data can be kept secret from me and other developers by the company, I'm assuming they encrypt it before uploading it for example, but allow the valid users to access it.

Is there a way to do this without putting a technical burden on the investors so that they don't have to have anything more than a username and password whilst also not storing their "keys" in the database so that a developer could technically decrypt it.

Comment: Assuming you use a key for encrypting your database content you could store that key for each user encrypted using a key derived from the user's password (.e.g using PBKDF2). The only draw-back would be that resetting the password would no longer be possible.

Comment: Separate the Authorizations (the ability to view the data) from the Encryption (the transformation on the data). You can never completely protect the data in this instance; Admins and [likely] Developers will always have access. There is no technology you can throw at the problem. It's why the [NSA moved to reduce Admins by 90%](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-security-nsa-leaks-idUSBRE97801020130809) after the Snowden leaks.